# ConnectionError when using the OpenAI API via spacy-llm

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to use the `spacy-llm` package to experiment with various NLP tasks, and am keen to see what results I can achieve via the OpenAI API.

However, when I try to run the toy example provided by `spacy-llm` (Example 1 at https://spacy.io/usage/large-language-models#-api), I get a `ConnectionError` with error code 429:

```
>>> import spacy_llm
>>> from spacy_llm.util import assemble
>>> nlp = assemble("config.cfg")
>>> doc = nlp("You look gorgeous!")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1047, in __call__
    error_handler(name, proc, [doc], e)
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 1724, in raise_error
    raise e
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1042, in __call__
    doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {}))  # type: ignore[call-arg]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy_llm/pipeline/llm.py", line 145, in __call__
    docs = self._process_docs([doc])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy_llm/pipeline/llm.py", line 199, in _process_docs
    responses_iters = tee(self._model(prompts_iters[0]), n_iters)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy_llm/models/rest/openai/model.py", line 115, in __call__
    responses = _request(
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy_llm/models/rest/openai/model.py", line 86, in _request
    r = self.retry(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/admin/platform-api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy_llm/models/rest/base.py", line 147, in retry
    raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: API could not be reached after 34.710 seconds in total and attempting to connect 5 times. Check your network connection and the API's availability.
429     Too Many Requests
```

It seems to think there have been "Too Many Requests" - perhaps requests are being repeated in the background? Is there a way to disable that?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

For reference, I have also tried an example provided on the OpenAI website to make sure that my keys are working correctly, as below. This worked exactly as expected.

```
import os
import openai
openai.organization = "org-xxx"
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
openai.Model.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is to read a little more carefully - while my usage was $0, the remaining $18 of free credits was not available, and had in fact expired...